# How to chain two callback-type gain functions of the same object?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I have an object Word, which is a model from loopback ([http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Model#Model-Model.count([query],callback)](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Model#Model-Model.count%28%5bquery%5d,callback%29)). It has a set of interfaces for working with information. Namely it has 2 methods Word.count() and Word.find()

Both methods gets data by callback. I need to ask one method after another.

```
this.count({}, function (err, count) {
    if(err) {
        fn(err);
    }
    else {
               //here i want to call smth like
               //this.find({},function(err,result){..})
               //but can`t, cause "this" is undefine
    }
});
```

How can i make a chain?

Comment: `var that = this` and use `that`

Comment: Alternatively, use `function (err, count) { ... }.bind(this)`

Comment: thanks a lot. i tried to do this before posting, but smth was wrong
now everithing works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a common cause of js problems. A useful technique is to set it to a different variable so you can use it in a closure, like (it seems) you want to.

Does this work?

```
self=this;
this.count({}, function (err, count) {
    if(err) {
        fn(err);
    }
    else {
        self.find(...);
               //here i want to call smth like
               //this.find({},function(err,result){..})
               //but can`t, cause "this" is undefine
    }
});
```